# Load multiple JSON object

Tags: json, ajax

I am trying to load multiple JSON object from one file, but my attempts failed.
Here is my code which run to error when I tried to load .JSON file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "..data.json", 
        method: "GET", 
        success: function(data) {
           // do something
        },  
        error: function(data) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
  });
```

The file format what I am trying to load is the following:

[{"id_first":"1","data_first":"1"},{"id_first":"2","data_first":"2"}] [{"id_second":"1","data_second":"1"},{"id_second":"2","data_second":"2"}]

Is there any solultion for this problem? Thanks for helps in advance!

Comment: Check your url. Doesn't seem valid to me. The error is generated from the ajax request, not the json file. Also the JSON-like string contains 2 different JSONs.

Comment: The data.json is in the tmp folder, try without points  like data.json. When I try to load just the first object  ({"id_first":"1","data_first":"1"},{"id_first":"2","data_first":"2"}] the function working well, but the point is to work with the second object as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to change the json schema like this at the backend.

```
[
 [{
    "id_first": "1",
    "data_first": "1"
  }, {
    "id_first": "2",
    "data_first": "2"
 }],
 [{
    "id_second": "1",
    "data_second": "1"
 }, {
    "id_second": "2",
    "data_second": "2"
 }]
]
```

it more easier for you to process the data.

Comment: Thank for your help, the problem solved with your format.

Comment: I have one more question. Although the function loaded the json file, bit I can't push these to a variable. Do you have any advice? Here is my attempt: `  var data_second = [];
             for(var i in data) {
          data_second.push(data[i].data_second);
          
           console.log (data[i].data_second);`

Comment: i think you cannot push it. just solve your json schema from your api.